# ASP.NET Core Web API endpoint connection with database, best practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, endpoint

This question may be opinion based, but I'm looking for input to see if I can do this in a better way.
I'm trying to figure out how to let my Web API Controller retrieve objects from my database, while keeping them nicely separated.

I have a set of Persons in my sqlite database (through EFC):

```
public class Person {
    
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string HairColor { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string EyeColor { get; set; }
    [NotNull, Range(0, 125)]
    public int Age { get; set; }
    [NotNull, Range(1, 250)]
    public float Weight { get; set; }
    [NotNull, Range(30, 250)]
    public int Height { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Sex { get; set; }
}
```

And a Web API endpoint to retrieve persons, based on some query filterings, I'll show further below.

In many tutorials the DbContext is just injected directly into the Controller, and then in the endpoint method, they would get the DbSet and do some LINQ gymnastics to retrieve the objects.
But to me it seems that the DbContext is then very entangled with the Controller, and it feels wrong to expose the DbSet like that. It feels better to hide this behind and interface, and not expose the DbSet.

So I'm creating a class AdultRepo : IAdultRepo, which knows about the DbContext. In this interface I have a method, which takes a Func<Adult, bool> to use as a filter when searching for Adults:

```
public interface IAdultRepo {
 
    Task<IEnumerable<Adult>> GetAllByCriteriaAsync(Func<Adult, bool> criteria);
    
}
```

Here's the method in AdultRepo:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Adult>> GetAllByCriteriaAsync(Func<Adult, bool> criteria) {
        IEnumerable<Adult> adults = famCtx.Adults.Where(criteria);
        
        return adults.ToList();
}
```

(I didn't find a way to make this part async)

And then in my Controller, I have my endpoint GET-method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Adult>>> GetAdultsAsync
    (
        [FromQuery] string firstname,
        [FromQuery] string lastname,
        [FromQuery] string jobTitle,
        [FromQuery] string hairColor,
        [FromQuery] string eyeColor,
        [FromQuery] string sex,
        [FromQuery] int? age
    ) {
        Func<Adult, bool> criteria = adult => {
            if (firstname != null && !firstname.Equals(adult.FirstName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;
            if (lastname != null && !lastname.Equals(adult.LastName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;
            if (jobTitle != null && !jobTitle.Equals(adult.JobTitle, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;
            if (hairColor != null && !hairColor.Equals(adult.HairColor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;
            if (eyeColor != null && !eyeColor.Equals(adult.EyeColor, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;
            if (sex != null && !sex.Equals(adult.Sex, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) return false;
            if (age != null && age != adult.Age) return false;

            return true;
        };

        IEnumerable<Adult> adults;
        try {
            adults = await iAdultRepo.GetAllByCriteriaAsync(criteria);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Console.WriteLine(e);
            return BadRequest(e.Message);
        }

        return Ok(adults);
    }
```

Does this make sense? Is there a better/cleaner/simpler way to do this?

Comment: I guess nicer way would be to put these criteria fields into separate object `AdultCriteria`; then add to repository class method like `GetAllByCriteria` which will have as the input that `AdultCriteria` class, and all the magic with comparisons which you have in the Controller class will be done in that method. So Controller will just initialize new `AdultCriteria` object, and pass it into `GetAllByCriteria` method. And all the details will be hidden inside repository method.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/infrastructure-persistence-layer-implementation-entity-framework-core#using-a-custom-repository-versus-using-ef-dbcontext-directly

Comment: You should not use Func<T, bool> as that will cause loading all the data in the table and filtering on client side. You need to use Expression<Func<T, bool>>, but that does come with some limitations for building the filters.

Comment: https://github.com/ardalis/ApiEndpoints

Comment: This question has been answered a million times, e.g. by the link @devNull posted.

Answer (score 2):

When using the repository pattern always return an `IQueryable` not an `IEnumerable` it gives you more control over your query and you can decide when to materialize with `ToListAsync()` or `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`...etc and what extension to call before (like deciding  when to call `AsNoTracking()` or not for example), and its lighter on the memory. See [here](https://code-maze.com/net-core-web-development-part4/)

This will be the contract for all your db entities:

```
  public interface IRepositoryBase<T>
    {
        IQueryable<T> FindAll();
        IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
        void Create(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
    }
```

And this is the base class for each repository:

```
public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> : IRepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {
        protected RepositoryContext RepositoryContext { get; set; }
        public RepositoryBase(RepositoryContext repositoryContext)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext = repositoryContext;
        }
        public IQueryable<T> FindAll()
        {
            return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>();
        }
        public IQueryable<T> FindByCondition(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression)
        {
            return this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Where(expression);
        }
        public void Create(T entity)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }
        public void Update(T entity)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Update(entity);
        }
        public void Delete(T entity)
        {
            this.RepositoryContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's a whole debate over using repositories. What do they actually offer you? the EF Context implements the Unit of Work. The DbSets are your repositories. Is there value in wrapping them like this?

Comment: @SimonHalsey The whole idea of the wrapper has some good benefits: Being able to swap implementations for testing, Construct entites from different data sources, working with data sources other than EF (like having different contexts) this can isolate the consumer of the repo from this operation and it wouldn't care where the data is coming from. Change ORMs without affecting the business logic. I additionally wrap the repos with interfaces into a single DI service that wouldn't leak DB implementation to the invoker thus completely hide EF from the business logic.

Comment: @SimonHalsey Some devs have their own way of wrapping the db context for testability and other purposes instead of this pattern and in some cases it may be an anti pattern it depends on the project.

Comment: "depends on the project" is the key phrase. Don't just copy a pattern because it says so here. Some of EF makes it very hard to mock in unit testing, so that might be a reason. A repository also gives you a location to put re-usable queries.

Comment: @SimonHalsey its a double edged sword like almost all patterns, everything has its use case and my answer was based on the fact that op was already using the pattern.